# Keep text labels on same relative x position to the main axes for all zoom levels while maintaining an absolute y position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add annotation lines to my plot with hlines() and add text labels.
I want to position the labels with a certain margin from the left axis that stays the same on all zoom levels of the plot. The y position however should move with the line.

This is my code to draw the lines:

```py
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle='round, pad=0.3', ec='r', fc='w', alpha=1)
xmin, xmax = axis.get_xlim()
ax.hlines(pos, xmin, xmax, colors='r')
if not label is None:
    ax.text((xmax-xmin)*0.05 + xmin, pos, label, ha='left', va='center', bbox=bbox_props)
```

This is the original plot:
[image: Original plot]
and after zooming in, the label moves to the right
[image: Zoomed in, labels moves]
I want that it stays at the same distance like this:
[image: Should look like this]

The y position behaves perfectly fine.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to position the label's x coordinate in axes coordinates, not in data coordinates,

```
ax.text(0.05, pos, label, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that you can transform a single coordinate. Thanks!
Do you know if I can use this transform expression for the hlines() function, too to set the xmin and xmax to 0 and 1?

Comment: I just checked myself: yes one can use transform for the hlines() function